# JAVA image request from multipart-form

Tags: java

I'm trying to redesign my code that originally took in JSON POST. To now take in images from POST requests. The problem is that when trying to debug it keeps giving me weird Unicode for the image data. I've tried looking into this problem from scratch, but all the examples I've been finding have been used for static images already on the hard drive.

I've tried this for my code inside my JSP file and it works fine for JSON data posts. Can someone tell me if I'm on the right path at all for this?

```
    try{

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer resp = new StringBuffer();
    while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
        resp.append(inputLine);
    }

    System.out.println("Images request line: \"" +resp.toString().substring(0, 200)+ "\"");

    in.close();

    }catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: Are you using plain Servlets or what for the service?

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve and what is in the request, but images are binary data, so it will not render any meaningful Unicode string. You should load it as `byte` array, not `String`.

Comment: I'm just using this JSP to grab what I need. then I send what I need to my java files to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder in 2004.